# Letsencrypt - I have specified the installer as webroot but it wants me to specify an installer

Tags: lets-encrypt

I don't have Apache. I do the lets encrypt /.well-known/acme-challenge/ files on my own node.js server on ubuntu 20.

I'm reading the le man page http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/certbot.1.html but, I'm confused. I can run this successfully:

`certbot certonly -d site.com -d www.site.com --force-renewal --webroot --webroot-path "/home/user/public_html" --non-interactive --agree-tos -m 'me@gmail.com'`

And it says "Congratulations!" and that I should use "certbot renew". In my undestanding the `certonly` does not install the cert and when I look at my site in fact the cert is not renewed. **(But I wan't to renew it.)**

So I run:

`certbot renew -d site.com -d www.site.com --force-renewal --webroot --webroot-path "/home/user/public_html" --non-interactive --agree-tos -m 'me@gmail.com'`

then it says:

With the webroot plugin, you probably want to use the "certonly" command, eg: certbot certonly --webroot (Alternatively, add a --installer flag. See https://eff.org/letsencrypt-plugins and "--help plugins" for more information.)

And I think, I have specified the installer as webroot!

let's look at `certbot --help plugins`:

```
plugins:
  Plugin Selection: Certbot client supports an extensible plugins
  architecture. See 'certbot plugins' for a list of all installed plugins
  and their names. You can force a particular plugin by setting options
  provided below. Running --help <plugin_name> will list flags specific to
  that plugin.

  --configurator CONFIGURATOR
                        Name of the plugin that is both an authenticator and
                        an installer. Should not be used together with
                        --authenticator or --installer. (default: Ask)
  -a AUTHENTICATOR, --authenticator AUTHENTICATOR
                        Authenticator plugin name. (default: None)
  -i INSTALLER, --installer INSTALLER
                        Installer plugin name (also used to find domains).
                        (default: None)
  --apache              Obtain and install certificates using Apache (default:
                        False)
  --nginx               Obtain and install certificates using Nginx (default:
                        False)
  --standalone          Obtain certificates using a "standalone" webserver.
                        (default: False)
  --manual              Provide laborious manual instructions for obtaining a
                        certificate (default: False)
  --webroot             Obtain certificates by placing files in a webroot
                        directory. (default: False)
  --dns-cloudflare      Obtain certificates using a DNS TXT record (if you are
                        using Cloudflare for DNS). (default: False)
  --dns-cloudxns        Obtain certificates using a DNS TXT record (if you are
                        using CloudXNS for DNS). (default: False)
  --dns-digitalocean    Obtain certificates using a DNS TXT record (if you are
                        using DigitalOcean for DNS). (default: False)
  --dns-dnsimple        Obtain certificates using a DNS TXT record (if you are
                        using DNSimple for DNS). (default: False)
  --dns-dnsmadeeasy     Obtain certificates using a DNS TXT record (if you
                        areusing DNS Made Easy for DNS). (default: False)
  --dns-gehirn          Obtain certificates using a DNS TXT record (if you are
                        using Gehirn Infrastracture Service for DNS).
                        (default: False)
  --dns-google          Obtain certificates using a DNS TXT record (if you are
                        using Google Cloud DNS). (default: False)
  --dns-linode          Obtain certificates using a DNS TXT record (if you are
                        using Linode for DNS). (default: False)
  --dns-luadns          Obtain certificates using a DNS TXT record (if you are
                        using LuaDNS for DNS). (default: False)
  --dns-nsone           Obtain certificates using a DNS TXT record (if you are
                        using NS1 for DNS). (default: False)
  --dns-ovh             Obtain certificates using a DNS TXT record (if you are
                        using OVH for DNS). (default: False)
  --dns-rfc2136         Obtain certificates using a DNS TXT record (if you are
                        using BIND for DNS). (default: False)
  --dns-route53         Obtain certificates using a DNS TXT record (if you are
                        using Route53 for DNS). (default: False)
  --dns-sakuracloud     Obtain certificates using a DNS TXT record (if you are
                        using Sakura Cloud for DNS). (default: False)
```

So I do the same but with `--installer "webroot"` and it errors:

Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
An unexpected error occurred:
zope.interface.exceptions.DoesNotImplement: An object does not implement interface

Please see the logfiles in /var/log/letsencrypt for more details.

How do I get it to install the cert?